# How to run a spring boot groovy project in vs code

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, groovy

made the default build of spring boot application using groovy (maven builder) in visual studio code when trying to run it gives the error "Failed to run this project 'demo' because it does not contain any main class." opened the same project in IntelliJ IDEA everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is an agile dynamic language for Java virtual machine, which is finally compiled into .class bytecode file to run the project.

Try to compile the groovy file which includes main method manually, then under **Maven** Selections, right click the project name, clean and compile the project again.

[image]